# 16*2 screen - Join the 5V pins together

Tags: hardware, screen

I am trying to add a 16*2 LCD Screen to an electronic boxe I am currently building, but when I connect the 5 V power supply to the screen my raspberry pi start to blink and then turn off...

I tried independtly the screen in the past it was working...

On a PCB board I have joined the two 5V Pins of the Raspberry Pi, which supply a ULN28001a for 4 relays and the Screen nothing else... Everything works except when I plug the Screen...
Do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are trying to take too much power from the 5V supply for the Pi, the screen, the ULN28001a IC *and anything that is connected to the USB ports that is not a powered Hub*!  Also, for that L.C. Display, does it have 5V or 3.3V inputs? Both types exist!

Are you the person who put these posts on the forum at [rasbperrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=126942)?

More generally, which pins are you using and relating to that, which set of pin "numbers" are you then referring to {"Broadcom", "WiringPi" or actual "header" pins - and on which model of Pi...!}

EDIT: The "later" model Pis will flash/turn off the Power LED when the 5V drops below a certain level (and also flash a "rainbow" coloured square in the top right of the display); FWIW those models can also show a "red" square that indicates that the CPU/GPU is overheating...

Comment: Yes I have also posted on the forum of raspberry Pi